# How to properly update Android BillingFlowParams methods deprecated

Tags: android, android-billing

I have

```
BillingFlowParams purchaseParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSku(skuId).setType(billingType).setOldSkus(oldSkus).build();
```

but now

```
setSku

setType

setOldSkus
```

are all deprecated.

I want to update the old code without releasing an update that mess with the active and future subscriptions.
How should I properly update the above code?

Currently I use
a `String myProduct="my_newsweek_1";`
to identify the purchase and `BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS` to identify the type,
and I simply pass `null` to `setOldSkus`

Documentation reports that

`setSku (String sku)` and `setType (String type)` have been replaced with `setSkuDetails(SkuDetails)`
(this `SkuDetails` object receives only a `String` as parameter in the constructor and throws `JSONException` so seems It doesn't work with old `String` constants)

and

`setOldSkus(ArrayList<String> oldSkus)` has been replaced with `setOldSku(String)`

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code to below for newer billing lib version

```js
  mBillingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                            .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))
                            .setSubscriptionUpdateParams(BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
                                .setOldSkuPurchaseToken(oldPurchaseToken)
                                .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.DEFERRED)
                                .build())
                            .build()
                        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(context, mBillingFlowParams)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need BillingFlowParams for `launchBillingFlow()`. You can create your SkuDetails with your own json string but it is not the intended way. You should at first call `querySkuDetailsAsync()` and get necessary skuDetailsList and then use them for `launchBillingFlow()`

```
public void querySkuDetailsAsync(@SkuType final String itemType, final List<String> skuList, final SkuDetailsResponseListener listener) {
    Runnable queryRequest = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Query the purchase async
            SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
            params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(itemType);
            mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                    new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                            //use skuDetails in skuDetailsList
                        }
                    });
            }
        };
    executeServiceRequest(queryRequest);
}

public void initiatePurchaseFlow(final SkuDetails skuDetails) {
   Runnable purchaseFlowRequest = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
      Log.d(TAG, "Launching in-app purchase flow.");
      BillingFlowParams purchaseParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetails).build();
         mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(mActivity, purchaseParams);
      }
   };
   executeServiceRequest(purchaseFlowRequest);
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I have asked. I know that I need `launchBillingFlow`, what I don't know is how to convert my sku parameters in a format suitable for the new versions of the deprecated methods

Comment: There is only one new version of deprecated methods and it is setSkuDetails(), so you need to pass SkuDetails object. And you get it by querySkuDetailsAsync().

Comment: I don't know how to convert my String constants in a `SkuDetails object`, in order to use `setSkuDetails`, for this reason I have asked here. Could you help me?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer you can at first convert your constants to json and create `new SkyDetails(jsonString)` but it is **NOT** the correct solution. Google wants you to get those details by  `querySkuDetailsAsync()` that's why those methods are deprecated.

Comment: @underoid is right. The idea is to write a function which first requests all your SKUs from google play with `querySkuDetailsAsync` and then you get a list of all your `SkuDetails`. Save one of the SkuDetails from the list you need, for example in mySkuDetail. Then call `BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(mySkuDetail).build();`. That's it. No need to create a json. The constants are not even defined by google to prevent users from creating their own custom jsons.

Comment: This has been outlined here in the google developer blog: https://developer.android.google.cn/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes?hl=fr#set-sku

Comment: I cannot understand why you need 10 lines of code just to provide a param. How flawed can a language or library be. Why not just keeping it a simple string. Annoying builders everywhere doesnt make sense